# How can I track DOB that is given in text format in a Wikipedia page and assert that one DOB is greater than other one using cypress? learning cypress

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

This is what I am working on:

- Accesses this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beatles
- Clicks on the first link to Paul McCartney’s Wikipedia page
- Keeps track of the date Paul McCartney was born
- Goes back to The Beatles page
- Clicks on the first link to John Lennon’s Wikipedia page
- Keeps track of the date that John Lennon was born
- Asserts that John Lennon was born before Paul McCartney

```js
describe('iCONNECT Test Suite', function () {
  it('Test Case 1', function () {
    cy.visit('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beatles')
    cy.get(':nth-child(8) > [href="/wiki/Paul_McCartney"]').click()
    cy.get('.mw-parser-output > :nth-child(6)').contains('18 June 1942')
    cy.go(-1)
    cy.wait(7000)
    cy.get(':nth-child(8) > [href="/wiki/John_Lennon"]').click()
    cy.get('.mw-parser-output > :nth-child(6)').contains('9 October 1940')
    expect(1940).to.be.lessThan(1942)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
describe('iCONNECT Test Suite', function () {
  it('Test Case 1', function () {
    cy.visit('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beatles')
    cy.get('.infobox-data')
      .find('li > [href="/wiki/Paul_McCartney"]', {timeout: 7000})
      .click()
    cy.get('.infobox-data', {timeout: 6000})
      .eq(0)
      .should('be.visible')
      .invoke('text')
      .should('include', '18 June 1942') //Assert the birth day for Paul McCartney
    cy.get('.infobox-data')
      .eq(0)
      .find('span')
      .invoke('text')
      .then((text) => text.slice(2, 6))
      .as('paulBirthYear') //Get Birth year for Paul McCartney
    cy.go(-1)
    cy.get('.infobox-data')
      .find('li > [href="/wiki/John_Lennon"]', {timeout: 7000})
      .click()
    cy.get('.infobox-data', {timeout: 6000})
      .eq(0)
      .should('be.visible')
      .invoke('text')
      .should('include', '9 October 1940') //Assert the birth day for John Lennon
    cy.get('.infobox-data')
      .eq(0)
      .find('span')
      .invoke('text')
      .then((text) => text.slice(1, 5))
      .as('johnBirthYear') //Get Birth year for John Lennon
    cy.get('@paulBirthYear').then((paulBirthYear) => {
      cy.get('@johnBirthYear').then((johnBirthYear) => {
        expect(+johnBirthYear).to.be.lessThan(+paulBirthYear) //Assert John Lennon is older than Paul McCartney
      })
    })
  })
})
```

Test Runner Execution:

[image: Test runner execution]

Comment: could you help me understanding which text you invoked and used the .slice method to grab the 2nd to 4th elements as birth year for john and 3rd to 5th for paul? my question may seem naive.  I just wanna learn :)

Comment: For Paul McCartney `cy.get('.infobox-data').eq(0).find('span').invoke('text')` gives `(1942-06-18) 1942-06-18 (age 79)` and after slice it gives you `1942`. Similarly, for John Lennon we get `(1940-10-09)1940-10-09` and after slice, it gives you `1940`. Then we are converting these strings into numbers by adding `+` in front of the strings like `+johnBirthYear` and `+paulBirthYear` and then finally making the assertion using `expect`.

Comment: Thanks, Alapan.  One simple basic question:  cy.get('@paulBirthYear').then((paulBirthYear) => {
      cy.get('@johnBirthYear').then((johnBirthYear) => {
        expect(+johnBirthYear).to.be.lessThan(+paulBirthYear) //Assert John Lennon is older than Paul McCartney
      })
    }) . Why did you use nested function over here?

Comment: In order to access and compare the values of both the birth years.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to do in this way:   `cy.get('.infobox-data')
        .eq(0)
        .find('span')
        .invoke('text')
        .then(function(text){
          text.slice(2, 6)
        }).as('paulBirthYear').then((paulBirthYear)=> cy.log(paulBirthYear))`  but it is grabbing the whole text : (1942-06-18) 1942-06-18 (age 79).  This is same as : `.then((text) => text.slice(2, 6))` right? I mean then function the way I wrote?